# Plot using Seaborn in for loop with legends

Tags: seaborn

I am trying to generate plots using loop, while doing that I am getting multiple/repetative legends in every loop.

Here is the code:

```
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(11.7,8.27)})
palette = sns.color_palette("Pastel2", 2)
tsne = TSNE(n_components=2)

label_original=[0,1,0.....]

for i in [1,2,3,4,5,6]:
    for j in [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100]:

    data2= some_data_aclculated
    X_embedded = tsne.fit_transform(data2)
    sns_plot =sns.scatterplot(X_embedded[:,0], X_embedded[:,1], hue=label_original, legend='full')
    sns_plot.figure.savefig("%s_%s_plot.png" % (i,j))
```

In 2nd iteration I get 2 repetative legends, in 3rd iteration I get 3 repetative legends and so on.
How to get rid of repetative legends?

Attached the image:

[image]

Comment: So the aim is to add succively new points to the figure and save each step? Then, `legend=False` should be sufficient in each, but the first step.

Comment: In every step data2 is different so plotting data2 in lower dimension and saving the image

Comment: But the figure will contain all data2 that has been calculated in previous steps. I wonder if that is desired or not.

Comment: No no... data2 has same dimension but the values are completely different. I am not appending anything from previous data. Just new plot everytime

Comment: What you currently do is: You plot n points, save the figure, plot another n points in the same figure, save the figure again (now the figure contains 2*n points), etc.

Comment: ImportanceOfBeingErnest  : How to get rid of previous data in same figure.